# Input's caret height

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I need help to change the caret's height - without changing the visual (hacks/tricks allowed as long as they work).
With that I mean I don't want to change the font's size (height and width), margins, paddings, color, background, border, etc, and if I do change it to achieve the caret's style, make it possible so I can put it back like a normal input, with it's styling capacities.

My best attempt was the following code:

```css
body{
  background-color: lightBlue;
}
#background{
  color: red;
  height: 61px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  width: 173px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,calc(1/3));
}
#text{
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  left: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
}
```

```html
<span>Caret's height (pixels):</span>
<br>
<br>
<input placeholder="15 (default)" spellcheck="false">
<br>
<br>
<input id="background" oninput="document.getElementById('text').value=this.value" spellcheck="false">
<input id="text" placeholder="5 (1/3)" onfocus="this.blur()" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1">
```

Ignore the text's selection weirdness if you need. I'm not caring about that for now.

If you have a way better solution, let me know. This is just some tests I have been doing, I don't exactly need the color to be red and the other attributes to be the way they are, but I do want it to still be possible to change them to whatherver I want.

Here's how it looks to me in case people don't get the same (using Chrome):
[image]

Comment: With a quick glimpse, I'd say not possible with an input element. You could emulate the input with a content editable div.

Comment: It's not technically possible @Teemu, that's why I said hacks/tricks. Workaround is the correct word.

Comment: To the people editing: please don't turn the code in a snippet as that normally ruins the visual of the result. To make sure you're getting the same as I, test it in your pages.

Comment: @user7393973 snippet works fine for me http://c2n.me/3HiIm9u

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - The text's position (`<input id="text">`) is different but I will leave it as it is, it's not a big issue.

Comment: @user7393973 yeah, 'almost' fine)

Comment: What you can do to get the desired effect is that you can create your own custom font while keeping its size small (in the font file itself.)
The height of caret adjusts to the `font-size` CSS property, but you can deliberately make your font smaller in its font file itself.

Comment: @MehulMohan - That's an ideia, "a little complicated and I'm not 100% sure if it works" ideia, but it's still an idea. I feel sad whenever I find these little things (customize limitations) that should be way more easy to change but that just isn't possible to do like any other attribute, `input::caret{ height: X px; }`. I'm sure the people/team that makes these things could make it possible, but they just don't add them.

Comment: @user7393973 Well that's not a thing which is used (or demanded) a lot. And sure these effects can be achieved by making use of some javascript. This is the best thing I like about programming, if you're creating something new which nobody did before, its usually awesome. :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to do this? I see no plausible reason that justifies the effort of making this work cross-platform. On top of it, it breaks with UX conventions. This doesn't mean you have no valid reason - I'm just curious what it could possibly be;)

Comment: @Christoph: Sometimes, I just like to do what can't be done. Push the limits of the programming language. See if it's possible, just for fun. No need to make it cross-platform, I'm only testing it's power to do things that look like they should be easy but actually aren't. Everyone still uses a lot of the browsers's default looks and behaviours and that's why I do these things...

Comment: @DiegoRios: That's me. :\

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, via "hacks".

Instead of an input box, you'd need a combination of javascript, css and span's...

[source: codepen](http://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/LkLApz)

[source: blog](https://benfrain.com/creating-a-custom-input-cursorcaret/)

[source: jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mz5z7vc/)

```js
document.documentElement.setAttribute("class", "js");

var searchFauxInput = document.querySelector(".fb-Search_FauxInput");
var searchBox = document.getElementById("Input");

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function copyInput(event) {
      searchFauxInput.textContent = searchBox.value;
      searchBox.setAttribute("value", searchBox.value);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.fb-Search {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 5px 70px 5px 5px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.fb-Search_Input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.js .fb-Search_Input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.fb-Search_FauxInput {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #777;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  height: 3px;
}

.js .fb-Search_FauxInput {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.fb-Search_Input:focus ~ .fb-Search_FauxInput {
  -webkit-animation: pulseAttention 1.5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1) forwards infinite;
  animation: pulseAttention 1.5s cubic-bezier(.215, .61, .355, 1) forwards infinite;
}

.fb-Search_Label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.fb-Search_Input:not([value=""]) ~ .fb-Search_Label {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulseAttention {
  50% {
    border-color: green;
  }
}

@keyframes pulseAttention {
  50% {
    border-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-Search">
 <input id="Input" class="fb-Search_Input" value="">
 <span class="fb-Search_FauxInput" dir="rtl"></span>
 <label class="fb-Search_Label" for="Input">Search</label>
</div>
```